# internal server error while uploading a file

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jax-rs

I want to upload a file using *restfull* webservice.And when i am exposing 
  this rest service , i am getting 500*(Internal Server Error)*.

> resource.java class

```
   @Path("/resource")
   public class Demo{
   private static final String FOLDER_PATH = "C:/uploaded_license/";    
      @POST
      @Path("/upload")
      @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fis,
           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fdcd) {

         OutputStream outpuStream = null;
         String fileName = fdcd.getFileName();
         System.out.println("File Name: " + fdcd.getFileName());
         String filePath = FOLDER_PATH + fileName;

         try {
             int read = 0;
             byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
             outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
             while ((read = fis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                 outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
             }
             outpuStream.flush();
             outpuStream.close();
         } catch(IOException iox){
             iox.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
             if(outpuStream != null){
                 try{outpuStream.close();} catch(Exception ex){}
             }
         }
         return "File Upload Successfully !!";
    }
  }

This is the rest service in which *FOLDER_PATH* is the path where the 
uploaded file will saved.
```

> > upload.html

```
     <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery jsTree Plugin Demo</title>

  </head>

   <form action="rest/resource/upload" method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <p>Select a file : <input type="file" name="file"/></p>
           <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
            </form>
     </div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

> Web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"version="3.1">
  <display-name>uploadfile</display-name>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>mypackage.upload</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

> Pom.xml
>
> > The pom.xml where all the dependencies are defined-

```
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.25.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>2.13</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

> error

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception

    type Exception report

    message Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from 
    fulfilling this request.
    exception
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet 
    threw exception

    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
    (AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke
    (ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke
    (AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service
    (CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
    (AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
    (AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
    (NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run
   (NioEndpoint.java:1489)java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run
    (TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    root cause

    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of 
    the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
    [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public 
     java.lang.String
     mypackage.upload(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.
     FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.; 
     source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-
     data], producedTypes=[text/plain], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, 
     suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, 
     invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class 
     mypackage.upload, handlerConstructors=
     [org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@39ede858]}, 
     definitionMethod=public java.lang.String 
     mypackage.upload(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.
     FormDataContentDisposition), parameters=[Parameter [type=class 
     java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class 
     org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, 
     source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, 
     nameBindings=[]}']
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize
     (ApplicationHandler.java:555)
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500
    (ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call
    (ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call
    (ApplicationHandler.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException
       (Errors.java:255)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>
       (ApplicationHandler.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init
        (ServletContainer.java:177)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init
        (ServletContainer.java:369)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
        (AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke
        (ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke
        (AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service
        (CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
        (AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
        (AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
       (NioEndpoint.java:1533)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run
        (NioEndpoint.java:1489)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
        (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
        (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)   
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run
        (TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: do you have an stack trace?

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception

Comment: That is not an stack trace. That is a message. Exception happens during the init. The stack trace should tell you where is exception is happening. It should be part of the response in most cases. Verify your web.xml with this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994690/which-init-param-to-use-jersey-config-server-provider-packages-or-javax-ws-rs-a/23041643

Comment: now i have added the stack trace

Comment: Away from computer to verify this but check fully qualified name of the class is the same in web.xml and source file

Comment: yes it is same...

Comment: Will have more time later today

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using "file" twice in method parameter annotations. The stack trace points in that direction. If this works, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to inti `ApplicationContext.xml`. Ex. :-

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```