# HTTP Status 404 error in Rest WS concept

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web.xml

I am just Rest API concept with `hello world` program. I'm following some tutorial videos and trying the same program But I'm not getting the expected result.

Here is my `Book.java`

```
package com.book;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/book")      //URI
public class Book {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayHelloXML() {
        String response = "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + "<hello>Hello World</hello>";
        return response;
    }

}
```

and the `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name>WSdemo</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

      <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>book</param-value>
      </init-param>

      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
</element>
```

And I'm using `Tomcat v8.0` server.
But as I run the application, I am getting out put as  [image: RestErrPic]

Can somebody give me key ideas for learning the concept of RESTfull web service?

Comment: Should be `<param-value>com.book</param-value>`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994690/which-init-param-to-use-jersey-config-server-provider-packages-or-javax-ws-rs-a

Answer (score 0):

There should be correct configuration in web.xml

I've edited my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- <element> -->
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name>WSdemo</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

      <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.book</param-value>
      </init-param>

      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
<!-- </element> -->
```

And I got the correct output as 
[image: output]

Thank You.